# match string and delete lines up to matched string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the file output

```
xyz abc
abc xyz
apple orranges fruits 
train bus flight
        airbus greatbus
 vegetables not in place.
```

I have to find pattern "train bus flight" and delete all the above lines include train bus flight

output should be:

```
     airbus greatbus
 vegetables not in place.
```

Could anyone please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried? Show us your code and the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if each line contains the text you are looking for.

```
# Assuming the input file is called "input.txt"
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin:
  # Read all the lines
  buff = iter(fin.readlines())

# For the output file do the following
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
  # Iterate over every line
  for line in buff:
    # Check if the text you look for is not in the line
    if "train bus flight" not in line:
      # If not found check next line
      continue
    else:
      # Another for loop to start from where you are
      for line in buff:
        # Write the rest of the lines
        fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete the line which has all three mentioned word in any position of that line? I am not sure why the 
`xyz abc` and `abc xyz` lines are got deleted. These do not have `train bus flight` in them.

Then here is a way to do so.

**Python 3 solution:**

```
with open("a.txt","r") as fp:
    line_list = fp.readlines()
    for line in line_list:
        if all(word in line for word in ["train", "bus", "flight"])==False:
            print(line[:-1])
```

**Output:**

```
xyz abc
abc xyz
apple orranges fruits 
        airbus greatbus
 vegetables not in place
```

**a.txt:**

```
xyz abc
abc xyz
apple orranges fruits 
train bus flight
        airbus greatbus
 vegetables not in place.
```

Comment: I want to delete all the lines upto string macthed ..thats the reason those are deleted